# Proving that E(E(X|Y)) = EX

Tags: probability-theory

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$So I know that $\E X = \E(\E(X\mid Y))$, I also looked up the definition on how it's proved on Wikipedia, the only part which leaves me hanging, is this:

[image: Proof of law of total expectation]

So first line to second line, this one I undestand, as you can write $P=(X=x\mid Y=y) = P(X=x, Y=y) / P(Y=y)$, so $P(Y=y)$ cancels out. But from second line to third line, I don't get what is happening there. So we sum up all the $Y$s, yet why does it, so to say, disappear?

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^n P(X=i\cup Y=j)=P(X=i)$ if the possible values of $y$ are $1,2,\dots n$.

Comment: So, what you're stating is that if we go over the whole probability space $\Omega$, then the "condition" doesn't really matter any more (so Y degrades down to $\Omega$)?

Comment: It's just basic set theory: $$\bigcup_y\big(\{X=x\}\cap\{Y=y\}\big)=\{X=x\}\cap\big(\bigcup_y\{Y=y\}\big)=\{X=x\}\cap\Omega=\{X=x\}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_y  P(X=x, Y=y) = P( \cup_y \{ X=x, Y=y\} ) = P(\{X=x, Y \text{ is anything}\}) = P(X=x)$$.

Comment: Yeah, the comment under my post kinda made me realize that if we set Y to any value, it ends up so-to-say cancelling out. Is the comment what I posted under my question the correct way to describe this?

Comment: Your comment uses non-standard terminology, but the idea is normally called marginalization.

Answer (score 0):

If $\Pr(Y=1\text{ or }Y=2\text{ or }Y=3) = 1$ then
\begin{align}
\Pr(X=8) & = \Pr\Big( (X=8\ \&\ Y=1) \text{ or } (X=8\ \&\ Y=2) \text{ or } (X=8\ \&\ Y=3)\Big) \\[10pt]
& = \Pr(X=8\ \&\ Y=1) + \Pr(X=8\ \&\ Y=2) + \Pr(X=8\ \&\ Y=3) \\[10pt]
& = \sum_y \Pr( X=8\ \&\ Y=y).
\end{align}